# Vuejs 3: Increase and decrease z-index on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to increase and decrease `z-index` on button click. For example, I need to increase `z-index` on the div when I go to the next page (class `turn` with animation adds), and decrease `z-index` when I go to prev page (class `turn` removes):

```
// ViewBook.vue - template
<div
   class="book__page book__page--right"
   :class="{ turn: pageStates.page3 }"
   :style="calcZIndex('page3')">
   <ViewSomeContact :togglePageState="togglePageState" />
</div>
//...(more pages following)
```

Here's what I tried to do. Currently, if I press next button, the first page turns as intended and the next ones fall under the first one, which indicates there's some issue with `z-index`. Also, I can't see the `z-index` adding to the elements at all in devtools:

```
// ViewBook.vue - script
const pageStates = ref({
    page3: false,
    page2: false,
    page1: false,
});

const calcZIndex = page => {
    const index = Object.keys(pageStates.value).findIndex(p => p === page);
    if (pageStates.value === true) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            {
                return { zIndex: 20 + index };
            }
        }, 500);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            {
                return { zIndex: 20 - index };
            }
        }, 500);
    }
};

const togglePageState = page => {
    pageStates.value[page] = !pageStates.value[page];
};
```

And then I just provide the `calcZIndex`, inject in the button component and call it on button click. But it seems like it doesn't work as intended:

```
// ItemTurnBtn.vue
<template>
    <button class="book__nav-btn" @click="handleButtonClick">
        <slot> </slot>
    </button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue';
    const calcZIndex = inject('calcZIndex');
    
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        playSfx();
        calcZIndex();
    };
</script>
```

I'm looking for a possible solution. Let me know if you find a way to do it.

Update:

It partially works with this code. By partially I mean that the pages turn in the correct order, but the animation doesn't work as intended - some pages turn too quick because of the rapid `z-index` change only after the page turn animation appears. I need to add a small delay (500ms) in order for this to work correctly, but I can't find the way to do it:

```
// ViewBook.vue

const calcZIndex = page => {
    const index = Object.keys(pageStates.value).findIndex(p => p === page);
    if (pageStates.value[page]) {
        return { zIndex: 20 - index };
    } else {
        return { zIndex: 20 + index };
    }
};
```

Comment: it's a problem with using `setTimeout`.  If you remove setTimeout I believe it will work. 
 If you want to keep setTimeout, try binding some reactive variable to `:style` and update calcZIndex to assign its result to that variable rather than returning the result directly.

Comment: @yoduh i switched `zIndex: 20 + index` to `zIndex: 20 - index` inside`if` and conversely in `else`, now the order of the pages is correct when I turn them. I also removed `setTimeout` but still the first turn is fine and the rest turns make pages fall under the first page. I need setTimeout because I have a style on `turn` class that rotates the page in Y axis and the transition is `1 sec`, so I need this kind of delay to make pages turn correctly. Do you have any possible solution for my issue? It seems like you're the only one who replied to me so far.

Comment: @yoduh I posted the update in the question, please check.